# SQL Server query condition as a text stored in a table column

Tags: sql-server

[image]

I want my query get the employees who have the rank depending on the condition 
in `Condition` column in a SQL Server query

Comment: I don't think this will end well here.  SQL is very good at storing _data_, but the logic for querying that data belongs in the query itself.

Comment: You'll need to read about dynamic SQL. Make sure you understand the pitfalls before you go down that road. The conditions you have above could easily be stored in a table instead.

Comment: oh so i will get other way .

Comment: i want like this select *from employee where rank in(select condition from conditiontb where mgr=111) but the back condition value is text so cause err

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that by using dynamic SQL in stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SelectEmpWithComdition @mgr int
AS
BEGIN
declare @query varchar(max), @condition varchar(max)
set @query = 'select empid, empname, rank from employees where '
select @condition = Condtition from Conditions where mgr = @mgr

set @query = @query + @condition
exec sp_executesql @query

END
```

Answer (score 0):

It will give you some idea.

```
Declare @Command varchar(Max)
Declare @condition varchar(100)

Select @condition = condition from [rank] where mgr = 2

Set @Command = 'Select * from Empployee
where ' + @condition

Execute (@Command)
```