# TSQL Method to Join Two Tables Where ON Condition is Stored As String

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm basically trying to join two tables where the join criteria are stored as a string.

- I have data stored in TableA that includes the fields `TREATY_NO` and `CO_CODE`.
- I also have TableB shown below. I am trying to return the `LookupCode` where the `IncomingData` field is true.

```sql
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
|                                     IncomingData                                      |                  LookupCode              |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
| CHARINDEX('99FW',TREATY_NO,3)>0 AND (CO_CODE='PAZ' OR CO_CODE='PNJ' OR CO_CODE='PRU') | '5-0089-2013-0500-01-A-2013-Y-USD-AL-01' |
| CHARINDEX('99FV',TREATY_NO,3)>0 AND (CO_CODE='PAZ' OR CO_CODE='PNJ' OR CO_CODE='PRU') | '5-0089-2013-0500-01-A-2013-Y-USD-AL-01' |
| CHARINDEX('99FK',TREATY_NO,3)>0 AND (CO_CODE='PAZ' OR CO_CODE='PNJ' OR CO_CODE='PRU') | '5-0089-2013-0500-01-A-2013-Y-USD-AL-01' |
| CHARINDEX('99FL',TREATY_NO,3)>0 AND (CO_CODE='PAZ' OR CO_CODE='PNJ' OR CO_CODE='PRU') | '5-0089-2013-0500-01-A-2013-Y-USD-AL-01' |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
```

For example, if a row in TableA has the `TREATY_NO = 'ABC99FWTZ'` and `CO_CODE = 'PAZ'` then `LookupCode` should = `'5-0089-2013-0500-01-A-2013-Y-USD-AL-01'`

```sql
+-----------+---------+----------------------------------------+
| TREATY_NO | CO_CODE |               LookupCode               |
+-----------+---------+----------------------------------------+
| ABC99FWTZ | PAZ     | 5-0089-2013-0500-01-A-2013-Y-USD-AL-01 |
+-----------+---------+----------------------------------------+
```

I'm sure there must be a method for doing this, but I can't figure out what to search for. I've looked into cursors for doing it row by row, but a set result seems like a better solution.

I have also been trying to follow the first answer in this question. But the problem is different enough.
[SQL Server query condition as a text stored in a table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38966999/sql-server-query-condition-as-a-text-stored-in-a-table-column)

Even a keyword for the problem I'm trying to solve would be very helpful.

Thank you!

Comment: That's a challenging desing choice. You need dynamic SQL to generate the query strings, then execute them.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any say in the design. I was looking into dynamic SQLs, but got stuck on how to apply it to all rows without going row by row.

Comment: If TREATY_NO and CO_CODE are always of the same length, then you could solve it using SubString

Comment: When you say the incoming data is in that string format, is it a fixed string always of that format, or is it variable? If its fixed then you could pick out the 4 important parts using string functions.

Comment: The field IncomingData  has several formats, but not an unlimited number. It wouldn't be impossible to pick out the important parts, but it would require several layers of cases to do.

Comment: How many rows are in the TableB?

Comment: Is it possible that a row in TableA matches the conditions found in two different rows in TableB? If yes, how many rows should be found in the result for that row?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to change the design of the problem. I cannot think of any efficient way to do it. However, if it is an one time task, you can combine a cursor with a dynamic Sql to make it work. For example,

```
--we declare the necessary variables that we will use
DECLARE @filterText as VARCHAR(512)
DECLARE @sqlText as VARCHAR(1024)

DECLARE @TREATY_NO as VARCHAR(24)
SET @TREATY_NO = 'ABC99FWTZ'
DECLARE @CO_CODE as VARCHAR(24)
SET @CO_CODE = 'PAZ'

DECLARE @tempStr AS VARCHAR(512)

--we init a cursor that will get the filter from the tableB which then we create a dynamic SQL
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT IncomingData 
FROM TableB

OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @filterText  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
      --we replace the variables from the text as parameters
      @tempStr = REPLACE(@filterText, 'TREATY_NO', '@TREATY_NO')
      @tempStr = REPLACE(@filterText, 'CO_CODE', '@CO_CODE')
      
      --we create the SQL query as a string where the WHERE check first the row to be the one from the cursor and then the actual filter if it is true or not
      @sqlText = 'SELECT @TREATY_NO, @CO_CODE, LookupCode FROM TableB WHERE @filterText = IncomeData AND ' + @tempStr

      --we execute the select
      EXEC (@sqlText)

      FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @filterText 
END 

CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```